# create a multiple data frames from a single data frame in r

Tags: r

I've got a large data frame `finaldata` and i would like to produce a bunch of other smaller  data frames `explanatory1, explanatory2 e.t.c....` consisting of 10 columns each from `finaldata`

I'm trying to do this using a for loop but its throwing me an error `attempt to apply non function`

```
for(i in 1:length(finaldata)/10) {
  nam <- paste("explanatory", i, sep = "")
  assign(nam, finaldata[,10(i):10(i)+10])
}
```

I have also tried

```
for(i in 1:length(finaldata)/10){
  assign(paste("explanatory",i,sep=""),finaldata[,10(i):10(i)+10])}
```

But this gave me the same error, from what I understand the error is being caused by my passing `finaldata[,10(i):10(i)+10]` as an argument to assign, but I don't see why it wouldn't work ina  for loop, or be any different from passing `finaldata[,10:10+10]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, do you want to split up `finaldata` into multiple data.frames, with columns 1:10, 11:20, 21:30, ..., respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `split`:

```
ll <- lapply(split(colnames(finaldata),rep(seq_len(ncol(finaldata)/10),each=10)),
       function(x)finaldata[,x])
```

This will create a list. But You can extract from it separate variables (not recommanded) :

```
ll <- setNames(ll,paste0("explanatory",seq_along(ll)))
list2env(ll)
```

Comment: This does the first part, but doesn't produce separate lists, instead produces a data frame of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Create sample data to play with:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 10, 33))
```

Find the number of dataframes you're going to create:

```
number_of_dataframes <- ceiling(ncol(df) / 10)
```

Loop through the dataframes, finding a range of columns to use for creating that individual dataframe. Use `assign` to give each one a unique name:

```
current_column <- 1
for (i in 1:number_of_dataframes) {
  start_column <- current_column
  end_column <- min(current_column + 9, ncol(df))
  assign(paste0("df",i), df[ , start_column:end_column])
  current_column <- end_column + 1
}
```

The `min` check makes sure you don't attempt to assign more columns than existed in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there... Try this...

```
for(i in 1:ncol(finaldata)/10) {
  nam <- paste0("explanatory")
  if((10*(i - 1)+10) > ncol(finaldata)){
        assign(nam, finaldata[,(10*(i-1) +1):ncol(finaldata)])
  }else{
        assign(nam, finaldata[,(10*(i-1) +1):(10*(i - 1)+10)])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This did exactly it, thanks to @canary_in_the_data_mine. Choose "`number_of_dataframes`" to be some factor of "`finaldata`" that you want for your purpose, then:

```
number_of_dataframes <- ceiling(ncol(finaldata) / 5)
current_column <- 1
for (i in 1:number_of_dataframes) {
  start_column <- current_column
  end_column <- current_column + 5
  assign(paste0(explanatory,i), finaldata[,start_column:end_column])
  current_column <- end_column + 1
}
```

The only change I made was to end_column.